# Thread stops all code for some reason - Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a small loop that starts 5 threads,
but for some reason the loop stops after it starts the first loop and not continues to start the other threads

```
       for i in range(5):
           
           t = threading.Thread(target=Loop.fatman(ws_server=ws_server, sessionid=sessionid, serverid=serverid, myuid=myuid, tokenn=tokenn))
           t.daemon = True
           threads.append(t)
       

       print(print("loop finished (all threads created)")
```

for some reason it doesn't go to the `print("loop finished (all threads created)")`

Comment: You should provide a minimal runnable example of the code which doesn't work. The code now doesn't even start the threads so I have a hard time believing this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 2 fundamental mistakes in your code.

1. You have to pass a callable to the `Thread` `target`, but you are calling it in your code - `t = threading.Thread(target=Loop.fatman(ws_server=ws_server, sessionid=sessionid, serverid=serverid, myuid=myuid, tokenn=tokenn))` this line actually executes the function `fatman()`, So a thread is not in picture, the main thread will work.
2. You are creating your thread (even though the callable is called), but you are not starting them any where.

See the code below. It can provide some insight, may not be a fully working code - as I don't know if you have posted a complete functional unit.

```
_callable = Loop.fatman
kwargs = dict(ws_server=ws_server, sessionid=sessionid, serverid=serverid, myuid=myuid, tokenn=tokenn)

for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=_callable, kwargs=kwargs)
    t.daemon = True
    # start your thread, just not create
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

print("loop finished (all threads created)"
```